# Will declaring a variable inside/outside a loop change the performance?

Tags: c#

Is this:

```
foreach(Type item in myCollection)
{
   StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
}
```

much slower than:

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

foreach(Type item in myCollection)
{
   sb = new StringBuilder();
}
```

In other words, will it really matter where I declare my `StringBuilder`?

Comment: Similar to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2447475/best-practice-for-creating-objects-used-in-for-foreach-loops

Comment: An unrelated error is that the second version should be initializing to null to avoid an excess allocation.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You could maybe gain some performance, if you write this:

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
foreach(Type item in myCollection)
{
   sb.Length = 0;
}
```

So you have to instantiate the StringBuilder just once and reset the size in the loop, which should be slightly faster than instantiating a new object.

Comment: +1: depending on the size of the built string and the resulting internal buffer in sb, this could make a measurable difference.

Comment: It might, but it also might not.  When you call `ToString`, it copies the buffer.  I'd benchmark it, assuming there was any reason to think it was performance-sensitive.

Answer (score 15):

No, it will not matter performance-wise where you declare it.

For general code-cleanliness, you should declare it in the inner-most scope that it is used - ie. your first example.

Comment: This should compile into the same IL anyway I think.  Well, it would if he weren't initializing sb twice.

Comment: Correct me if I am wrong, but if you declare it inside the loop won't that render it unusable outside of it (undeclared)?

Comment: @NullUserException Yes, you are right. But if you don't need it outside the loop, it is clearer to declare it inside the loop

Answer (score 2):

In the 2nd example you're creating an extra instance of StringBuilder. Apart from that they are both they same, so the performance issue is negligable.

Comment: This should be a comment to the question in my opinion.

Comment: @Shaihi - Why? w69rdy is giving an answer to the question.

Answer (score 1):

There isn't enough code here to clearly indicate a performance difference in your specific case.  Having said that, the difference between declaring a reference variable inside of a loop like this vs. outside is trivial for most cases.

Answer (score 1):

The effective difference between your two code samples is that the second will allocate 1 more instance of `StringBuilder` than the first.  The performance impact of this as compared to the rest of your application is essentially nothing.

Answer (score 0):

Best way to check is by trying both methods in a loop, about 100.000 each. Measure the amount of time each 100.000 iterations take and compare them. I don't think there is a lot of difference.
But there is a small difference, though. The first example will have as many variables as the number of iterations. The second example just has one variable. The compiler is smart enough to do some optimizations here, so you won't notice a speed improvement.
However, if you don't want to use the last object generated inside the loop once you're outside the loop again, then the first solution would be better. In the second solution, it just takes a while before the garbage collector will free the last object created. In the first example, the garbage collector will be a bit faster in freeing the object. It depends on the rest of the code but if you store a lot of data in this StringBuilder object then the second example might hold on to this memory a lot longer, thus decreasing the performance of your code *after leaving the loop*! 
Then again, if the objects eats up 100 KB and you have 16 GB in your machine, no one cares... The garbage collector will eventually free it again, probably as soon when you leave the method which contains this loop.

Answer (score 0):

If you have other similar type code segments, you could always profile or put some timers around the code and run a benchmark type test to see for yourself.  Another factor would be the memory footprint, which others have commented on.