# Is there any performance gain by declaring an object outside the loop

Tags: c#, performance

I have a code where I'm declaring an object inside a loop, like:

```
foreach(...)
{
ClassA clA = new ClassA();
clA.item1=1;
clA.item2=2;
ClassB.Add(clA);
}
```

Will there be any performance gain if I modify the code as follows:

```
ClassA clA;
foreach(...)
{
clA = new ClassA();
clA.item1=1;
clA.item2=2;
ClassB.Add(clA);
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I wouldn't of thought so as your still creating a new ClassA each time. How many loops are you expecting? What does ClassB.Add do?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Will declaring a variable inside/outside a loop change the performance?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3388536/will-declaring-a-variable-inside-outside-a-loop-change-the-performance)

Answer (score 4):

There is no performance gain as such. It only helps the variable to go out of scope later than sooner.

Comment: Exactly. The .NET GC will do a suitable job of cleaning it up. :)

Comment: If you don't use the variable after the loop, the scoping is purely lexical, ie. you could write code to use it at more places. However, for GC purposes, it makes no difference (at least in a Release build with no debugger attached), GC could reclaim the memory as soon as the loop has finished.

Comment: I'll add on what @Farlig has said: the MICROSOFT runtime will easily see that after the loop the clA is not used anymore and GC it. This isn't guaranteed. A not-so-intelligent JIT could not see this (and an even stupider JIT could not check if the clA, while defined in an inner scope, is not copied externally and, just to be sure, not mark it until the next GC run. I wrote it in a convoluted way. Let's say there is a List<ClassA> external to the scope. If you add clA to the List, the list will preserve it. If you don't add it, the list won't preserve it. A stupid JIT could not check this.)

Answer (score 3):

The compiler will automatically optimize the code to move the declaration outside the loop anyway, so there is nothing to gain by doing this.

For example

```
while(...){
  int i = 5;
  ...
}
```

Will be optimized be the compiler into this

```
int i;
while(...){
  i = 5;
  ...
}
```

Comment: Those two are not equivalent, by the way: the first initialises `i` to 5 at the top of every loop. You're right about the declaration, it's just your code samples are confusing as is. The second would be better as `int i; while (...) { i = 5; ... }`.

Answer (score 1):

The actual object allocation happens with `clA = new ClassA();` so unless you can move it out of the loop you won't get any performance gain.

Answer (score 1):

As everyone's said, not really, but I'd still change your code to:

```
foreach(...)
{
ClassB.Add(new ClassA() { item1=1, item2=2 });
}
```

Comment: You certainly *could* do that, but why do you think it's preferable?

Comment: Just because it looks nicer... (no temporary variable just to assign properties.) You may want to adjust the whitespace though, I'm too lazy to prettify things in SO.